# Как правильно говорить: "Что вам нужно?" или "Чего вам нужно?"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Полагаю, дело здесь в падежах подразумеваемого существительного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря;

НУЖНО, в функц. сказ.  2. **кого-что или чего.** Требуется, следует иметь. Срочно н. врача. Для этой работы н. двух человек. Мне н. сто рублей.

Итак, используются обе формы в зависимости от ситуации.

Пришёл человек. Что тебе нужно (В.п.)? - Мне нужно полотенце. - Чего тебе еще нужно (Р.п.)? - Мне нужно воды.

Родительный падеж обозначает **часть** неодушевленного предмета, но задающий вопрос этого не знает и может использовать любую форму.

В то же время при вежливом обращении на "вы" уместнее спросить: "Что Вам еще нужно?", а не очень вежливый вопрос обычно задается так: "Чего тебе?"

Comment: *Для этой работы мне **нужны два человека***, а не ***нужно двух человек***. *Нужно найти двух человек* — другое дело. *Мне нужны сто рублей* — это вообще **именительный падеж**. Понятно, конечно, что это не Вы ошиблись, а словарь, но если бы Вы заметили, можно было бы на него не ссылаться. ;) А в остальном поддерживаю Вас.

Comment: @Jasmin Ситуация в примере не вполне реалистична: человек только что сказал, что ему нужен предмет (что), а его дальше спрашивают излишне конкретно (чего), будто перед этим он попросил крупы отсыпать.

Comment: Артем,  здесь возможны две формы: безличное (мне нужно) или двусоставное (мне нужны...) предложения. Примеры из классиков с Р.п.:И вот, мне нужно двух секундантов. [В. В. Набоков. Подлец (1927-1929)] ... Для этого нужно двух человек: гениального портного и модного тенора... [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // Также в словаре: Мне нужно сто рублей (это статья на слово "нужно").

Comment: @Alex_ander  Ну, проситель уже надоел, теперь он может рассчитывать только на часть чего-то. Отсюда, как мне кажется,  и следует "невежливость" формы "чего".

Comment: Интересно) Просто вопросам "кого-что или чего" не соответствует, вот я и написал, что именительный падеж.

Comment: *Мне нужно, Пете нужно* — звучит нормально. *Для этого нужно двух человек* — по-моему, просторечно или устаревше (при всем уважении к классику).

Answer (score 0):

Правильно спрашивать "Что вам нужно?", хотя и это грубовато звучит (вежливо-холодная форма звучала бы: "Что вам угодно?").

"Чего" (нужно) выходит за рамки нормативной речи. Пример из словарной статьи Кузнецова ("Чего тебе: чаю или кофе?") ясно указует на неформальность отношений вопрошающего и потенциального отвечателя, некую вольготность в обращении или даже... амикошонство.

Это просторечие. И падежи абсолютно ни при чём.

---

Цитата с [лингвистического форума](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE.2892380/?hl=ru):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или вот, вопрос, заданный на сайте "Ответы" в категории "Лингвистика":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Галина, а это всё ненормативно? Вы не будете раскаиваться, если ее возьмете. Чего вам нужно? Денег? [К. С. Аксаков. Облако (1836)] А вы пристраиваетесь к чужим взглядам, к чужим способностям и… сами не знаете, чего вам нужно, что вы можете! [М. П. Арцыбашев. Тени утра (1905)] ?.. — Чего вам нужно? Что вы кидаетесь из стороны в сторону? [Вас. И. Немирович-Данченко. Цари биржи (Каиново племя в наши дни) (1886)]  Конечно,  персонажи находятся не в лучших отношениях, но   "что" вместо "чего" разве  что-нибудь изменит?

Comment: И в разговорной речи разве нельзя сказать: а чего тебе нужно, чего тебе больше всего хочется?  Неужели любое "чего" - это дурной тон. Мне иногда кажется, что жесткие уставки - это не признак высокой культуры, а признак снобизма. И нужно по крайней мере знать,  почему форма Р.п., используемая в ответе, в вопросе совершенно не допускается. И всегда ли так было?  И точно ли это ненормативно?

Comment: В разговорной можно всё. Примеры из девятнадцатого века нам сейчас не указ. Но вот я вижу в Ваших примерах то, что проглядела: *чего тебе больше всего хочется?* несомненно верная форма, а вот *чего тебе нужно?* - не-а! )))

Comment: Galina Avanesova сделайте милость, отмените свою редакция моего вопроса и верните ему грамотность написания.
Почему пишу здесь — именно недостаток слов, недоговаривание текста делает Ваш второй пример (как и всю реплику в целом) просторечным и неграмотным.

Comment: П.С. Очень жаль, что речь людей, на несколько порядков более грамотных, "нам сейчас не указ".

Comment: Вынесите свою проблему на всеобщее обсуждение: *отмените свою редакция моего вопроса и верните ему грамотность написания.* Я редактор, своих ошибок не вижу.