# Я благодарен за всё, что жизнь предлагает мне, я также благодарен за то, чего жизнь мне не предлагает

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Во второй части предложения "я также благодарен за то, чего жизнь мне не предлагает" правильно использовать `Чего` или `Что`?

Допускаю правильно написание в обоих случаях. Сомневаюсь еще по поводу смысла: форма `чего` интуитивно предполагает зависимую позицию, тогда как `что` звучит более чистой "благодарностью" жизни.

Comment: Вообще без разницы, фраза сама по себе дурацкая), нельзя быть благодарным за то, чего нет.

Comment: Что и чего - это союзные слова в обоих случаях, формы местоимения что (В.п и Р.п.). Форма ЧЕГО: Что жизнь предлагает?  Ничего не предлагает, чего не предлагает.  Р.п. используется при наличии отрицания.

Comment: @Sharon, т.е. правильная форма `за то, что предлагает` и `за то, чего НЕ предлагает`? Т.е. изначально в заголовке употреблено правильно, и будет неправильно употреблять "за то, что предлагает; за то, что не предлагает"? (или Р.п. при отрицании опционален?)

Comment: Вроде бы так. Насколько я помню, вопрос о выборе падежа ставится в других случаях. Можно посмотреть дискуссию: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435473/Как-правильно-говорить-Что-вам-нужно-или-Чего-вам-нужно

Answer (score 0):

Это сложносочиненное предложение, каждая часть которого является сложноподчиненным предложением. Во второй части может быть как союз "что", так и союзное слово "чего".
Поэтому можно выбирать, исходя из стилистики текста и личных пристрастий.На мой вкус "что" более формально (похоже на канцеляризм), чем "чего".